# Aurora MySQL Load Data Invalid utf8mb4 character string

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I am currently using MySQL Aurora 5.7 version.

I am trying to load data into MySQL with the 'load data' function.

MySQL's encoding is utf8mb4 and an error occurs when loading the data below.

Using latin1 encoding solves this problem, but in this case, there is a problem that Hangul is not displayed properly. (Korean Language)

So I can't use latin1 encoding.

In this case, what would be best to do it for loading?

We ask for your help.

CSV file : ^A means Ctrl + V + A

```
"sab:0000","þÿÿÿ^A"
"sab:0000","가나다"
```

The database language set is also utf8mb4.

```
CREATE TABLE `stats_string` (
  `_key` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `_value` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

$1, $2, $3 means  csv filename, table name, database name

```
load data local infile '$1' into table $2 CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '\"' ESCAPED BY '\b' lines terminated by '\\r\\n';" $3

ERROR 1300 (HY000) at line 1: Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '"'
```

Comment: Have you tried using `LOAD DATA .... CHARACTER SET euckr` to pick the Korean language non-unicode character set?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-asian-sets.html

Comment: I wonder...could it be your line endings are '\\n' and not '\\r\\n'?

Comment: and a `backspace` is a very weird choice for escape character

Comment: I saved your string into a text file, saved as UTF8 with no marker, connected to Aurora 5.7 and imported fine.  I had to remove the characters at the end of your `load file` which I suspect you didn't mean to copy (`;" $3`)

Comment: @O.Jones
Sorry for not telling you first.
Please understand that euc kr cannot be used due to internal reasons.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey    Oops. Sorry.  
The script was modified in the direction you gave, and the entire script is as follows.<br> ```mysql $_opt1 $_auth -e"load data local infile '$1' into table $2 CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '\"' ESCAPED BY '\b' lines terminated by '\\n'" $3``` .

And i got the below error.
```ERROR 1300 (HY000) at line 1: Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '"'```

Comment: @GarrGodfrey   
The reason I used the escape character '\b\ is because it contains the \b character in another line.

Comment: found the problem. Should be '\n' not '\\n'

Comment: After changing to'\n' I got the same error.
```mysql $_opt1 $_auth -e"load data local infile '$1' into table $2 CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '\"' ESCAPED BY '\b' lines terminated by '\n'" $3```
and ```ERROR 1300 (HY000) at line 1: Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '"'```

Comment: you might need '\r\n', depending on your line endings of the text file

Comment: @GarrGodfrey     
I felt strange and copied the csv I wrote on the stackoverflow. When comparing with xxd, it was confirmed that the hexa values ​​were not the same.
original file

```00000000: 2273 6162 3a30 3030 3022 2c22 feff ffff  "sab:0000","....
00000010: ffff ffff ff01 220d 0a                   ......"..```

stackoverflow
```00000000: 2273 6162 3a30 3030 3022 2c22 c3be c3bf  "sab:0000","....
00000010: c3bf c3bf 0122 0a                        .....".```

Comment: As a result of the test, I successfully loaded with text copied from Stack Overflow.
It seems to be a problem in hexa value.

Comment: your original file was probably not in utf8

Comment: @GarrGodfrey  You are a genius. I confirmed that the file encoding is binary, and I solved it by changing the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

All text files, without exception, are encoded in some character set or other. Many files are encoded in latin-1 and contain just its ASCII subset. That's true of most source code files, like HTML and so forth.

Other files are encoded in utf8. Some may be encoded in other character sets.

Your CSV file is encoded in some character set. You've determined that it is not latin-1 or utf8.  What character set is it? Ask the person who provided it, or analyze their workflow to figure it out. Then mention that character set in your `LOAD DATA` command.

MySQL has excellent support for converting between character sets. When you mention a character set in a `LOAD DATA`  command, you are instructing MySQL to convert the data  from that character set to the character set declared for the table (or column). You're not  changing the character set used in the table.

You mentioned in a comment that some sort of policy prevents you from using the `euckr` character set. Maybe your csv file comes to you encoded in that character set (I don't know whether it does; I don't have your file to look at). If so you will have to convert it upon loading. This sort of conversion requirement is very common when loading database tables.

Of course your data tables should be encoded in `utf8mb4` and not some legacy character set. But you may have to convert some of your source data from legacy character sets as you load it.